# Fitting a keras time-series generator in R to time-series and exogenous data

Tags: r, keras, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using the R interface to Keras (for the 1st time) with a `timeseries_generator` per the reprex below. How do I get `fit_generator` to complete all epochs?

I'm looking at custom generators as a possible alternative, but would ideally like to use the `timeseries_generator` assuming it is appropriate to my intended usage.

The intent is to predict the actual values several steps ahead by using the "feature" and three lagged copies of the actuals as predictors.

I'm assuming that differencing is not required since the feature is expected to indicate trend.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(keras)

# Function to generate multiple lags
# See: https://gist.github.com/romainfrancois/469ed8224ba4be48befec28cb1e1ff80
many_lags <- function(var, n = 10) {
  var <- enquo(var)

  indices <- seq_len(n)
  map(indices, ~ quo(lag(!!var, !!.x))) %>%
    set_names(sprintf("lag_%s_%02d", rlang::quo_text(var), indices))
}

# --- Simulate time-series
set.seed(42)
lags <- 3
samples <- 1000

ts <- tibble(time = 1:(1000 + lags)) %>%
  mutate(
    actual = seq(0.5, (1000 + lags) / 2, by = 0.5) + arima.sim(model = list(
      ar = c(0.2, 0.3),
      ma = 0.2,
      order = c(2, 1, 1)
    ), 999 + lags) %>% as.double(),
    feature = seq(0.5, (1000 + lags) / 2, by = 0.5)
  ) %>%
  mutate(!!!many_lags(actual, lags)) %>% 
  tail(samples)

ts %>% ggplot(aes(time, actual)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
# --- Centre & scale predictors
test_window <- 200

temp <- ts %>%
  head(-test_window)

col_mean <- map_dbl(temp, mean) %>% replace(c(1:2), 0)
col_sd <- map_dbl(temp, sd) %>% replace(c(1:2), 1)

train_data <- ts %>%
  head(-test_window) %>%
  scale(col_mean, col_sd)

test_data <- ts %>%
  tail(test_window) %>%
  scale(col_mean, col_sd)

# --- Create generator objects
batch_size = 5
length <- 5 # forecast timesteps

train_gen <- timeseries_generator(
  train_data[, 3:6],
  targets = train_data[, 2],
  length = length,
  sampling_rate = 1,
  stride = 1,
  start_index = 1,
  end_index = 600,
  shuffle = FALSE,
  reverse = FALSE,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

val_gen <- timeseries_generator(
  train_data[, 3:6],
  targets = train_data[, 2],
  length = length,
  sampling_rate = 1,
  stride = 1,
  start_index = 601,
  end_index = 800,
  shuffle = FALSE,
  reverse = FALSE,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

test_gen <- timeseries_generator(
  test_data[, 3:6],
  targets = test_data[, 2],
  length = length,
  sampling_rate = 1,
  stride = 1,
  start_index = 1,
  end_index = 200,
  shuffle = FALSE,
  reverse = FALSE,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

# --- Train the model
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_gru(
    units = ncol(train_data[, 3:6]),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    input_shape = list(NULL, ncol(train_data[, 3:6]))
  ) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

summary(model)
#> Model: "sequential"
#> ___________________________________________________________________________
#> Layer (type)                     Output Shape                  Param #     
#> ===========================================================================
#> gru (GRU)                        (5, 4)                        108         
#> ___________________________________________________________________________
#> dense (Dense)                    (5, 1)                        5           
#> ===========================================================================
#> Total params: 113
#> Trainable params: 113
#> Non-trainable params: 0
#> ___________________________________________________________________________

model %>% compile(loss = "mse",
                  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
                  metrics = list("mae"))

history <- model %>% 
  fit_generator(
    train_gen,
    steps_per_epoch = floor((train_gen$end_index - train_gen$start_index + 1) / batch_size),
    epochs = 100,
    validation_data = val_gen,
    validation_steps = floor((val_gen$end_index - val_gen$start_index + 1) / batch_size)
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I get the following messages:

```
2019-09-12 15:42:44.613462: I **tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA**
Epoch 1/100
119/119 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: 20351.4386 - mean_absolute_error: 120.7280 - val_loss: 77980.3295 - val_mean_absolute_error: 279.1719
Epoch 2/100
**WARNING:tensorflow:Your dataset iterator ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your iterator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches** (in this case, 11900 batches). You may need touse the repeat() function when building your dataset.
  0/119 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 120.7280 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0000e+00
```